# collection.findOne() return the same value for each item of a table

Tags: meteor

I know my question is kind of stupid one but i am stuck.
I have a table  of Contracts, each row have a update button ;
when i click on that button,  a modalthat contain the contract edit form is shown.
All work fine but my problem that the modal show the same contract for each row.
**For more description  this is a screenshot**
[image]

and this one for the modal [image]

this is my template helper

```
    Template.ContractsList.helpers({
    lists: function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('listsMethod');
        return Contracts.find({});

    },
    list: function() {
        return Contracts.findOne();

    }
});
```

and this is my Template event

```
Template.ContractsList.events({
    'click #editContract'(event) {
        $("#showModal").modal("show");
        console.log( Contracts.findOne({_id: this._id}) );


    },

    'click #hideModal'(event) {
        $("#showModal").modal("hide");
    },

});
```

and this is my Template

```
<template name="ContractsList">

    <div class="modal fade" id="showModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">edit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{#with list}}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label  class="select">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={{name}} />&nbsp;
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label  >Package</label>
                                <div >
                                    <select id="role" name="select" class="form-control" >
                                        <option  value="package" selected disabled hidden >{{package}}</option>
                                        <option value="freemium">freemium</option>
                                        <option value="bronze">bronze</option>
                                        <option value="silver">silver</option>
                                        <option value="gold">gold</option>
                                        <option value="platium">platium</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {{/with}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <Button class="primary" >Create contact</Button>
                    <Button class="secondary" id="hideModal">Cancel</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Package Type</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {{#each lists}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{package}}

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="editContract"><img src="../../../../../img/icons/addcontact-icon.png" /></Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

in my console log of the template event , i got the data correctly as i want

> {_id: "Qu8pTSzLDLGKRNRzd", name: "ilyes", package: "bronze"} {_id:
>   "w7NDzerxivAjhK3dy", name: "ee", package: "freemium"}

what should i do?

Comment: `findOne` simply fetches the first result of a query, if available. If you don't provide criteria like an id, you will get the first result of a query that matches all of the records, so it is to be expected. If you want to get the specific item, add an argument to the `list` helper.

Comment: but how can pass the id from the Events to the helper list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your click handler set a `Session` variable (or a `reactiveVar`) and then use it in your `list` helper:

Event handler:

```
'click #editContract'(event) {
  $("#showModal").modal("show");
  console.log( Contracts.findOne({_id: this._id}) );
  Session.set('currentRecordId',this._id);
},
```

Helper:

```
list() {
    return Contracts.findOne(Session.get('currentRecordId');
}
```

Comment: thanks it work :D , but is there another way except the session ?

Comment: @IlyesAtoui: as explained by MichelFloyd, you can instead use a `ReactiveVar`, it is the same idea but not at the app level. Both solutions take advantage of Meteor and Blaze's reactivity. The old school way would be to "manually" rebuild/re-assign the content of your modal inputs in your event.